# How to give different tooltips to different columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tooltip

I have created table in Power BI.  While giving tooltips, I want to display Tooltip-1 to 2nd column and Tooltip-2 to 3rd column as shown in the image.  How to do this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have add a soultion did it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

In a matrix visual you can do this by putting the tooltip visuals for every column one above the other on a single tooltip page.

- Now you change background settings of the tooltip visuals to 100% transparency.
- Then you make sure that text elements are only visible if the desired column is hovered over with a measure like (used as formating measure for font color)

  ```
  Transparency =
  IF(
      SELECTEDVALUE(tabl1[column1]) = "column title in matrix",
      "black",
      "#FFFFFF00" // 00 means 100% transparency
  )
  ```
- Charts like line charts etc. for their graphs need to use a logic like

  ```
  Conditional Sum =
  IF(
     SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Column1]) = "Column title in matrix",
     SUM(Table2[Column1]),
     BLANK()
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to solve your problem is  **Power BI report page tooltip**.

duplicate your page **step 1**

in duplicated page remove all other visual except your table make sure that table is in position of top left and make sure it is visible **step 2**

in page information activate tooltip **step 3**

in page size,select type of page tooltip(it is not necessary important but it helps to have better tooltip) **step 4**

go back in tooltip section of your table visual, set the type of report page **step 5**

set the page to the page you have duplicated  **step 6**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I could do what you suggested.  However, what I need is (1) to show tooltip 1 (say 4th column of brandname) as tooltip for 1st column (Brandname) in table; (2) to show tooltip 2 (say 5th column of brandname) as tooltip for 2nd column (Total Returns) in table and may be some other column as tooltip for my 3rd column (say Gross Profit) in the table.

Comment: in step 2 it is possible to have your aforementioned columns as your tooltip.

Comment: (1) When I change pagesize to Tooltip, the position of the table changes from Topleft to middle.  (2) After doing all this, my table in "Duplicate Of Page 4' becomes tooltip for Page 4 for all the columns.

Comment: it suppose to happen, before changing the pagesize to tooltip, you should change the position of visual to topleft in order to make sure table shows values, you can change the table columns as you want to show other columns and it will tooltip for your entire table not single column.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it changes the tooltip as per our requirements, however, it changes tooltip for the entire table and what I want is to give different tooltips for different columns.